# Add MVC ValidationMessageFor to separate Div Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to add all of the @Html.ValidationMessageFor blocks to a div container in the footer of the MVC parent _layout.cshtml page? The code below shows the validation messages in the bottom div, but I would like to display them in the footer of the _Layout.cshtml DIV using jQuery.

```
@model Proj.ViewModels.ApplicationControllerViewModel
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Details" }))
{
    <div id="divApplication">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Name, new { @class = "formLabel" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Applicaiton.ID, new { @class = "Application-ID" }) 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Name, new { @class = "Application-Name" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ControllerList, new { @class = "formLabel" })
            @Html.DropDownList("ControllerList", Model.ControllerList, new { @class = "Application-ControllerList"})
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Abbreviation, new { @class = "formLabel" }) 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Abbreviation, new { @class = "Application-Abbreviation" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Description, new { @class = "formLabel" }) 
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Description, new { @class = "Application-Description", rows = 10, cols = 60 })
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Deployed Date", new { @class = "formLabel" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Applicaiton.DeployedOn, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "Application-DeployedOn" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Abbreviation)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.DeployedOn)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just put the div with the validation messages on the _Layout page?

Comment: As long as you have the validation enabled it will automatically fill in the validation messages

Comment: We will potentially have hundreds of .cshtml partial views containing validation messages. I beleive the ValidationMessageFor tags must contain the model components that are being validated. (i.e.. model => model.Applicaiton.Name) which reside in the partial view.

Comment: The validation is working correctly. I want a way to show the messages in the footer div, not inside the form block.

Comment: Right so you want to show them in a footer on the _Layout page instead

Comment: Yep. I want the messages to show up in the footer of the _Layout page.

Comment: So your **@Html.ValidationMessageFor** for all properties are stored in partial views?

Comment: Each model is validated in its own partial view.

Comment: I'm confused so your input fields are stored in partial views?

Comment: Have you tried making a javascript function that will automatically insert the html into the layout page whenever a partial view is loaded?

Comment: Correct, partial views contain the model data(form data).

Comment: Is this a single page app? Or do you have separate views for each form?

Comment: Seperate partial views for each form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna take a crack at this even though I'm still confused on how your html looks and these partial views. Use the **.html()** method on page load of your views. For instance if you're on the view listed above add an **id** to your validation divs as

```
<div id="ValidationDiv">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Abbreviation)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.DeployedOn)
 </div>
```

You're going to want to put the same **id** on all validation divs for views that contain input. Then in your _Layout view in the footer area set an empty div with an id as

```
<div id="ValidationHolder">

</div>
```

Then going bak to our views with inputs just a Javascript function that copies html from the **ValidationDiv** to the **ValidationHolder**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var partialViewDivHtml = $('#ValidationDiv').html();
    var layoutDiv = $($'#ValidationHolder');
    layoutDiv.html(partialVIewDivHtml);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the built in functionality to do this with a `@RenderSection` within the  `_Layout.cshtml`:

**_Layout.cshtml (simplified for example)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
   @RenderBody()
</div>
<div>
   @RenderSection("ValidationMessages", false)
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**View**

```
@model Proj.ViewModels.ApplicationControllerViewModel
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Details" }))
{
    <div id="divApplication">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Name, new { @class = "formLabel" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Applicaiton.ID, new { @class = "Application-ID" }) 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Name, new { @class = "Application-Name" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ControllerList, new { @class = "formLabel" })
            @Html.DropDownList("ControllerList", Model.ControllerList, new { @class = "Application-ControllerList"})
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Abbreviation, new { @class = "formLabel" }) 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Abbreviation, new { @class = "Application-Abbreviation" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Description, new { @class = "formLabel" }) 
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Description, new { @class = "Application-Description", rows = 10, cols = 60 })
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Deployed Date", new { @class = "formLabel" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Applicaiton.DeployedOn, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "Application-DeployedOn" })
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section ValidationMessages {
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Abbreviation)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Applicaiton.DeployedOn)
}
```